# Javascript - includes method when comparing 2 array's ids

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to compare two arrays `keyArray` and `checkArray` by id number. If `keyArray` has a matching id with `checkArray` then append the `name` to `#mainTitle` with an anchor tag, if it does not match then append to `#otherTitle` without an anchor tag.

I am attempting to check if the id exists in `checkArray` with `.includes()`.

At the moment, all 3 indexes of `keyArray` is going to the else condition, but if is done correctly, then the `id:2, name: online` from index 0 of keyArray should be appended as a hyperlink.

Is `includes` the method that I should be using in order to check if it has a matching id number from the first array?

My expected outcome is to have,"Online" appear under the `#mainTitle` with blue text because the `id:2` appears in both the arrays.

```js
let keyArray = [{"id": 2, "name": "Online"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Retail"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Store"}]
let checkArray = [[1, "Test"], [2, "Online"], [3, "Test2"], [10, "Test3"]]



for (let el of keyArray) {
if (checkArray.includes(el.id)) {

$("#mainTitle").append("<a href='/" + el.name + "/ '/> " + el.name + "  </a>");
 $("#mainTitle").append("<br />");
} else {
$("#otherTitle").append("<span>" + el.name + "  </span>");
$("#otherTitle").append("<br />");
}
}
```

```css
#mainTitle {
  color:blue;
}

#otherTitle {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainTitle"></div>
<div id="otherTitle"></div>
```

Comment: are you maybe looking for [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're checking against the value of checkArray.  For instance, the first time it checks, it sees `[1, "Test"]` instead of `1`.  You can map your checkArray using `.map(v => v[0])` to convert the array to one of all the first items from the array values (your index presumably), but I'm worried this data might not be truly representative of your actual data.  In any case, throwing in a `.map()` does produce the desired result:

```js
let keyArray = [{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Online"
}, {
  "id": 12,
  "name": "Retail"
}, {
  "id": 14,
  "name": "Store"
}]
let checkArray = [
  [1, "Test"],
  [2, "Online"],
  [3, "Test2"],
  [10, "Test3"]
]



for (let el of keyArray) {
  if (checkArray.map(v => v[0]).includes(el.id)) {

    $("#mainTitle").append("<a href='/" + el.name + "/ '/> " + el.name + "  </a>");
    $("#mainTitle").append("<br />");
  } else {
    $("#otherTitle").append("<span>" + el.name + "  </span>");
    $("#otherTitle").append("<br />");
  }
}
```

```css
#mainTitle {
  color: blue;
}

#otherTitle {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainTitle"></div>
<div id="otherTitle"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed response, made it very clear.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Just as a quick note, if this is the final code, you should probably move the map outside of your for loop.  It's not critical with such a small array, but if you end up using a larger dataset, running map every time you loop might get expensive (if the compiler doesn't fix it for you).

Comment: Just checking if I understood correctly, but by moving the map outside of the loop, I would declare a variable equaling the .map value? Then using that to compare if the id exists in that array?

Comment: @maimok yes, that's correct.  Again, it's not that big of a deal, but I thought I'd mention it.